# Enclosing a command in escape characters in bash

Tags: bash

I have a command in quotes:

```
 ssh -i "/home/$USER/$KEY" "$USER"@"$WORKER1IP"   "echo 'if [[ `uname -a` == Darwin* ]]; then' >> /home/$USER/tachyon-0.5.0/conf/tachyon-env.sh"
```

The "uname" part has to be written literally, not executed. I tried using "\" before the 'uname' part, but I don't know how to close it. Can someone help please?

Comment: OK, I fixed it by \'uname -a\'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
ssh -i "/home/$USER/$KEY" "$USER"@"$WORKER1IP"   "echo 'if [[ \"\$(uname -a)\" == Darwin* ]]; then' >> /home/$USER/tachyon-0.5.0/conf/tachyon-env.sh"
```

and this too:

```
ssh -i "/home/$USER/$KEY" "$USER"@"$WORKER1IP"   "echo 'if [[ \`uname -a\` == Darwin* ]]; then' >> /home/$USER/tachyon-0.5.0/conf/tachyon-env.sh"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(...)` with escaped `$` in BASH:

```
ssh -i "/home/$USER/$KEY" "$USER"@"$WORKER1IP"   "echo 'if [[ \$(uname -a) == Darwin* ]]; then' >> /home/$USER/tachyon-0.5.0/conf/tachyon-env.sh"
```

Comment: No, that is printing the result of uname -a in the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Use a here document instead, which simplifies the nested quotes.

```
ssh -i "/home/$USER/$KEY" "$USER@$WORKER1IP" <<EOF
    echo 'if [[ $(uname -a) == Darwin* ]]; then' >> "/home/$USER/tachyon-0.5.0/conf/tachyon-env.sh"
EOF
```

Comment: I guess OP wants `'EOF'` (in single quotes).

Comment: Maybe, unless `$USER` needs to be expanded locally. It is in the original.

Comment: Oh I see, however it should not make a difference if you expand `$USER` remotely or locally since OP connects as `$USER`. An alternative would be to use `$HOME` there. Without single quotes around `EOF` it makes no sense since you would evaluate the output of the local `uname` command remotely.