# Escape characters in bash

Tags: bash

I have a line in my script here:

```
"echo 'CONF_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"' >> /home/$USER/tachyon-0.5.0/conf/tachyon-env.sh"
```

The portion CONF_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )" has to be written as it is onto the tachyon-env.sh file. I have tried many combinations of escape characters, but either the "cd" and "pwd" commands are getting executed, or there is a syntax error. Does anyone know how I might print the line literally onto the file? Thanks in advance

The full line:

```
ssh -i "/home/$USER/$KEY" "$USER"@"$WORKER1IP" "echo 'CONF_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"' >> /home/$USER/tachyon-0.5.0/conf/tachyon-env.sh"
```

Comment: Why do you have the whole line in double quotes?

Comment: Just single quote the string `echo 'CONF_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )' >> /home/$USER/tachyon-0.5.0/conf/tachyon-env.sh`

Comment: it will be executed after ssh-ing to another machine

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enclosing a command in escape characters in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29868221/enclosing-a-command-in-escape-characters-in-bash)

Comment: You have asked almost the same before ^^^ ..

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes, the configuration involves many escape characters, and I am not good in bash really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
'echo "CONF_DIR=\"\$( cd \"\$( dirname \"\${BASH_SOURCE[0]}\" )\" && pwd )\"" >> /home/$USER/tachyon-0.5.0/conf/tachyon-env.sh'
```

This too:

```
"echo 'CONF_DIR=\"\$( cd \"\$( dirname \"\${BASH_SOURCE[0]}\" )\" && pwd )\"' >> /home/$USER/tachyon-0.5.0/conf/tachyon-env.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try single-quoting everything except the single quotes inside your line. Use `\'` for the single quotes:

```
ssh -i "/home/$USER/$KEY" "$USER"@"$WORKER1IP" 'echo '\''CONF_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"'\'' >> /home/$USER/tachyon-0.5.0/conf/tachyon-env.sh'
```